# Determine whether file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I go about checking on whether a path is either a directory or a file?

```
 var fs = require('fs')
 var directory = '/path/to/directory'
 var dirContents = fs.readdirSync(directory)
 // [".DS_Store", "file01.file", "file02.file", "foo", "bar"]
```

I understand that node's fs has `fs.Stats` with `stat.isFile` and `stat.isDirectory`, but how do I use those in a loop function to determine what is a file and what is a directory?

Comment: use the sync version if you need it done _inside_ a loop, or just make it all async and gravy

Comment: so you want to know, for the array returned from readdir, what is a file and what is a directory? Like you would want to get an array back like `[true, true, true, false, false]` where the booleans represent the result of `stat.isFile`?

Comment: What I wanted to do was to check to see if something was either a file or a directory, and then stick either a file or directory icon from font-awesome in front of each `dirContents[i]` to be listed within a `<li>` element.

so, for `dirContents[0]` to have `'<li><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + dirContents[0]`

Comment: and you want to know how to do it async right?

Comment: And, are you using `koa.js` or `express.js` (or something else)?

Comment: sync-ness doesn't matter all that much for the app.  I just tended to stick with sync because I wanted to keep things in written order to take place.  I was going to have the user set a directory to watch, and then have a library side panel, kind of like atom's Project sidebar

Comment: I'm using `electron` for the app. No `koa` nor `express`.

Comment: OK, well you know that node is single threaded, right? So if you make it sync you're completely blocking the app?

Comment: I understand.  It is just a comic book reader app I'm building to learn node.js with.  If doing async ends up working better, i'll switch over, but I just wanted to know how to check if `dirContents[i]` is either a file or directory, as I don't understand how exactly to use `stats.isDirectory()` nor `stats.isFile()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it sync then its really easy (although maybe not a very good idea).

```
let contents = fs.readdirSync(dir);
let stats = contents.map((dirEntry) => {
    return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, dirEntry));
});
stats.forEach((s) => {
    // isFile is just a function available on the returned stat object
    console.log(s.isFile());
});
```

For async, its only slightly different. You'll want to use the `async` npm library, which takes care of things like this.

```
let async = require('async');

fs.readdir(dir, (err, contents) => {
    async.map(contents, (dirEntry, callback) => {
        fs.sync(path.join(dir, dirEntry), callback);
    }, (stats) => {
        // do something with stats array here
    });
});
```

Comment: Neat!  Thanks, Kevin